# python numpy MKL ERROR

Tags: numpy, compiler-errors, python-3.x, activestate

I am running ActiveState Python 3.2, and getting this cryptic error:

```
D:\code>python
ActivePython 3.2.1.2 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 18 2011, 14:31:09) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1]])
>>> y = np.array([3, 4, 5])
>>> be = np.linalg.lstsq(x,y)

MKL ERROR: Parameter 5 was incorrect on entry to DGELSD

MKL ERROR: Parameter 5 was incorrect on entry to DGELSD
>>>
```

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be no answer to that. The best I can do is provide [the link to my bug report](http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=91901) to ActiveState which is now being looked into.

Comment: I'm sorry, it appears that the entire bug section of Activestate website is gone. I have searched for whether they have moved the issues somewhere else, but found nothing.

If you are getting this exact error message on the more recent versions of ActiveState python, you may want to create a new bug report. By now, the entire stack changed a lot, so even parameter 5 may no longer be the same parameter as in 2012.