# linearRegression() returns list within list (sklearn)

Tags: python, list, regression

I'm doing multivariate linear regression in Python ([sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares)), but for some reason, the coefficients are not correctly returned as a list. Instead, a list IN A LIST is returned:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
# clf.fit ([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])
clf.fit([[394, 3878, 13, 4, 0, 0],[384, 10175, 14, 4, 0, 0]],[3,9])
print 'coef array',clf.coef_
print 'length', len(clf.coef_)
print 'getting value 0:', clf.coef_[0]
print 'getting value 1:', clf.coef_[1]
```

This returns the values in a list of a list [[]] instead of a list []. Any idea why this is happening? Output:

```
coef array [[  1.03428648e-03   9.54477167e-04   1.45135995e-07   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
length 1
getting value 0: [  1.03428648e-03   9.54477167e-04   1.45135995e-07   0.0000000
0e+00 0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
getting value 1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regress.py", line 8, in <module>
    print 'getting value 1:', clf.coef_[1]
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

But this works:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit ([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])
# clf.fit([[394, 3878, 13, 4, 0, 0],[384, 10175, 14, 4, 0, 0]],[3,9])
print 'coef array',clf.coef_
print 'length', len(clf.coef_)
print 'getting value 0:', clf.coef_[0]
print 'getting value 1:', clf.coef_[1]
```

Output:

```
coef array [ 0.33333333  0.33333333  0.33333333]
length 3
getting value 0: 0.333333333333
getting value 1: 0.333333333333
```

Comment: I'm not bent on trying to get sklearn to work. If there's another python library that will return correlation coefficients for a linear multivariate regression, I'd love to hear about it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed by updating two files in the SciKit-Learn folder.

The code is here:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/d0b20f0a21ba42b85375b1fbc7202dc3962ae54f

Answer (score 2):

I have never used the module for multivariate linear regression that you are referring to, so I cannot know why it is happening. But if you just want to solve you problem, you can flatten the list:

```
flat_list = clf.coef_[0]
```

<strike>If the list may have more than one sublist (and you want to combine them all into a flat list), then you can use a more general way to flatten it:</strike>

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in clf.coef_ for item in sublist]
```

**EDIT:** While waiting from a real explanation/solution from the package's developers, you could rely on a solution like this:

```
if isinstance(clf.coef_[0], list):
    clf.coef_ = clf.coef_[0]
```

That flattens the list only if there is a sublist inside of it.

Comment: It doesn't happen in every case, that's the problem. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Zach I see... After having a look at the documentation it is not clear at all why `coef` has different layouts depending on how you call `fit()`. At least such a possibility is not documented. You could try to contact [support](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/support.html) for that project. While you cannot find a _real_ solution for this, you can have a look at the edit on my answer.

Comment: @Zach Can you check the type of `clf.coef` and `clf.coef[0]` (when you have a sublist)? Actually you may get a `tuple` somewhere instead of a `list`.

Comment: They are both <type 'numpy.ndarray'>. I tried replacing list by numpy.ndarray but it doesn't recognize the data type..

Comment: If I create a `numpy.ndarray` with `x = numpy.ndarray((2, 3))`, then I get `type(x) -> numpy.ndarray`, `type(x[0]) -> numpy.ndarray`, `type(x[0][0]) -> numpy.float64`. I expected you would get `numpy.float64` for `type(x[0][0])` in the first example, and for `type(x[0])` in the second example. Is it not like that?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an issue with scipy.linalg. If you trace the call chain it goes first in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L218 and then it reaches the if statement at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/basic.py#L468. That `if` differentiates your two test cases. In the first case `m,n=2,6` and in the second you have `m,n=3,3`.

Comment: Any idea how to get around it? Or another way to get multivariate linear regression in python?

Comment: You can use `clf.coef_.flatten()` which collapses the array to one dimension.

Answer (score -1):

This really isn't a valid question about the Python language; it should be a question to the developers of sklearn. But... if you know that is the format your data will be returned in, you could just:

```
print 'getting value 0:', clf.coef_[0][0]
print 'getting value 1:', clf.coef_[0][1]
                                   ^^^
```