# Naming explanatory variables in regression output

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

Each one of my variables is a list on its own.

I am using a method found on another thread here.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

y = [1,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,6,5,4,5,4,3,4]

x = [
     [4,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,4,8,9,8,8,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
     [4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,8,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,6,5],
     [4,1,2,5,6,7,8,9,7,8,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,4,4,4]
     ]

def reg_m(y, x):
    ones = np.ones(len(x[0]))
    X = sm.add_constant(np.column_stack((x[0], ones)))
    for ele in x[1:]:
        X = sm.add_constant(np.column_stack((ele, X)))
    results = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
    return results
```

My only problem being, that in my regression output, the explanatory variables are labelled x1, x2, x3 etc. Was wondering if it was possible to change these to more meaningful names?

Thanks

Comment: You are probably looking for `pandas`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991445/run-an-ols-regression-with-pandas-data-frame

Comment: Thanks! This was quite useful, should probably learn how to use it

Comment: The code in the question comes form the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479064/multivariate-linear-regression-in-python/14971531#14971531, you probably should reference that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Searching through the [source](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/56e9c569fadb2805eeb3c64989ea122ea85a95af/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py#L2695), it appears the `summary()` method does support using your own names for explanatory variables.  So:

```
results = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
print results.summary(xname=['Fred', 'Mary', 'Ethel', 'Bob'])
```

gives us:

```
                                OLS Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.535
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.461
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     7.281
Date:                Mon, 11 Apr 2016   Prob (F-statistic):            0.00191
Time:                        22:22:47   Log-Likelihood:                -26.025
No. Observations:                  23   AIC:                             60.05
Df Residuals:                      19   BIC:                             64.59
Df Model:                           3
Covariance Type:            nonrobust
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fred           0.2424      0.139      1.739      0.098        -0.049     0.534
Mary           0.2360      0.149      1.587      0.129        -0.075     0.547
Ethel         -0.0618      0.145     -0.427      0.674        -0.365     0.241
Bob            1.5704      0.633      2.481      0.023         0.245     2.895
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        6.904   Durbin-Watson:                   1.905
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.032   Jarque-Bera (JB):                4.708
Skew:                          -0.849   Prob(JB):                       0.0950
Kurtosis:                       4.426   Cond. No.                         38.6
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably as close to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to adjust the names for the parameters

`summary` has an `xname` keyword that should work which can be used to just change the names in the summary table
http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.summary.html

When the model is created with a formula, then the parameter names are stored internally in the `data` attribute of models, `model.data.xnames`, and can be accessed through `model.exog_names`.

There is no proper setter method and it's not "officially" (*) supported, but AFAIK `model.data.xnames` can be overwritten, i.e. assign a new list of strings.
The list `model.exog_names` should only be changed inplace, because it's just another reference for the `model.data.xnames`.
These changes will be permanent and affect all uses of the parameter names.

(*) AFAIK: There are not unit tests for changing exog_names or xnames. Some models need to change the names depending on extra parameters that need to be estimated. The internal refactoring is going into the direction of using `param_names` so we can separate the names of the parameters from the names of the explanatory variables. The latter is needed in several newer models but is not relevant for OLS and many other traditional models.