# Linear regression of 2 lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, linear-regression

Hi I have 2 lists of numbers and I want to get the R^2 from a regular linear regression. I think the question has been posted a lot, but I just cannot find this somewhere.

My lists:

```
my_y = [2,5,6,10]
my_x = [19,23,22,30]
```

I have tried to change it to numpy arrays and then use sklearn to regress and get what I need, but I did not succeed. I used the following code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

my_y = np.array([2,5,6,10]).reshape(1, -1)
my_x = np.array([19,23,22,30]).reshape(1,-1)

lm = LinearRegression()
result = lm.score(my_x, my_y)
print(result)
```

Does anyone have a fast way to get the R^2 from doing a linear regression between those 2 variables?

My expected output from this regression is: R^2=0.930241

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run an OLS regression with Pandas Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991445/run-an-ols-regression-with-pandas-data-frame)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```py
import scipy

my_y = [2,5,6,10]
my_x = [19,23,22,30]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(my_x, my_y)
    
print(r_value**2)
```

and you get:

```
0.9302407516147975
```

---

From scipy version `'1.4.1'` (thanks to @FlamePrinz for having noted the issue for new versions of scipy):

```py
from scipy import stats

my_y = [2,5,6,10]
my_x = [19,23,22,30]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(my_x, my_y)

print(r_value**2)
```

Comment: This could cause the error: `AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'stats'`.

You would want to instead do:

`from scipy import stats`,

and then call it with: 

`slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(my_x, my_y)`

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look of the documentation, I see that `linear_model` needs you to provide a linear model as the name suggests. To get a simple R:

```
import scipy
my_y = np.array([2,5,6,10])
my_x = np.array([19,23,22,30])
R=scipy.stats.linregress(my_x, my_y)[2]
print(R)
```

> 0.9644898919194527

and `R**2` yields the desired result of 0.930.

Comment: Hi. Hmmm no? I was expecting the result to be equal to 0.930241. To get this result I used Excel's Regression tool and I should be able to get the same result with python as well...

Comment: Ok let me check.

Comment: Yeah. That is weird. Honestly, I do not know why is that. I don't work much with scipy, but It seems it works if I implement the other solution from sentence. I would look through the documentation, but I have to present some results in a few hours, and I do not have time. I will come back to this some other time and dig into it!

Comment: @George the OP asked for R-*squared*, not R.

Comment: @Adrian I went through the docs and as the name `sklearn.linear_model` suggests, a linear model needs to be provided, for the program to 'learn' and then put out a result. That's why it didn't work correctly.

Comment: @George your edit to square the value for R is now giving the correct result.