# Utlizing two indepedant variables and one dependant variables in linear regression using NUMPY

Tags: python, numpy, regression

I need help utilizing Numpy via Python for linear regression determination of two independent variables and one dependent variable. I have found this code snippet below for finding the r^2 values I believe from *http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiple_regression#Python*

```
import numpy as np

height = [1.47, 1.50, 1.52, 1.55, 1.57, 1.60, 1.63,
    1.65, 1.68, 1.70, 1.73, 1.75, 1.78, 1.80, 1.83]
weight = [52.21, 53.12, 54.48, 55.84, 57.20, 58.57, 59.93,
    61.29, 63.11, 64.47, 66.28, 68.10, 69.92, 72.19, 74.46]

X = np.array(height)[:, None]**range(3)
y = (weight)

print(np.linalg.lstsq(X, y)[0])
```

How can I edit this for determining the r^2 values for two independent variables and one dependent variable? Thanks

Comment: The name of the game is "multivariate linear regression", and the answer you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479064/multivariate-linear-regression-in-python. On the other hand, this makes your question a duplicate ;).

Comment: Thank you very much, very useful information indeed! I tried to search for a answer before submitting my question. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome! It's difficult when you don't know the name of what you are looking for!