# Access y-intercept in multiple regression using scikitlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've followed the accepted answer in this post:

[Multiple linear regression in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479064/multivariate-linear-regression-in-python)

In the comments, it mentions how to fit the line with a constant term (y-intercept). How do I access this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you fit the model, the intercept is available as `model.intercept_`. Here is an example:

```
# Example that should have intercept of 1
x = np.random.rand(10,3)
y = 1 + x.dot([1,2,3]) + 0.05 * np.random.rand(10)
lr.fit(x, y)
lr.coef_
>> array([ 1.01701958,  2.00951304,  3.00504058])
lr.intercept_
>> 0.99952789780697682
```