# Linear Regression with 3 input vectors and 4 output vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Task:

As an example, we have 3 input vectors:

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
bar = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
spam = [-10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -60]
```

Also, we have 4 output vectors that have linear dependency from input vectors:

```
foofoo = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
barbar = [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]
spamspam = [7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
hamham = [10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12]
```

How to use Linear Regression at this data in Python?

Comment: 3 input vectors and 4 output vectors don't make any sense.

Comment: check this out : http://connor-johnson.com/2014/02/18/linear-regression-with-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OLS (Ordinary Least Squares model)](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html) as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14971531/1771479):

```
#imports
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

#generate the input matrix
X=[foo,bar,spam]
#turn it into a numpy array
X = np.array(X).T
#add a constant column
X=sm.add_constant(X)
```

This gives the input matrix `X`:

```
array([[   1.,    1.,   50.,  -10.],
       [   1.,    2.,   60.,  -20.],
       [   1.,    3.,   70.,  -30.],
       [   1.,    4.,   80.,  -40.],
       [   1.,    5.,   90.,  -50.],
       [   1.,    6.,  100.,  -60.]])
```

And now you can fit each desired output vector:

```
resFoo = sm.OLS(endog=foofoo, exog=X).fit()
resBar = sm.OLS(endog=barbar, exog=X).fit()
resSpam = sm.OLS(endog=spamspam, exog=X).fit()
resham = sm.OLS(endog=hamham, exog=X).fit()
```

The [result](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults) gives you the coefficients (for the constant, and the three columns foo, bar, and spam):

```
>>> resFoo.params
array([-0.00063323,  0.0035345 ,  0.01001583, -0.035345  ])
```

You can now check it with the input:

```
>>> np.matrix(X)*np.matrix(resFoo.params).T
matrix([[ 0.85714286],
        [ 1.31428571],
        [ 1.77142857],
        [ 2.22857143],
        [ 2.68571429],
        [ 3.14285714]])
```

Which is close to the desired output of `foofoo`.

---

See this question for different ways to do the regression: [Multiple linear regression in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479064/multivariate-linear-regression-in-python)