# How to use predicted values as "X" to predict "y" and plot with confidence interval

Tags: python, linear-regression, timeserieschart

I need to predict "Y" variable using the already predicted values in "X". The highlighted yellow data is the current data. I used the timeseries Arima() model to predict the X values for next 25 periods.
Now, I need to use these values to predict my "Y" and then plot the "Y" over time period with confidence intervals.

I am new to the prediction models and need guidance on what to use that can help take the "X" values and predict for missing "Y"

Thanks!

Dataset: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use linear regression or facebook prophet
[Multiple linear regression in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479064/multiple-linear-regression-in-python)
https://facebook.github.io/prophet/