# 3D multiple linear regression along axis

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I would like to calculate a multiple linear regression of the form Y = a*X1 + b*X2 where Y.shape == X1.shape == X2.shape = (200,192,288). I would like to preform the multiple linear regression along axis=0. I believe an operation of this type should result in two arrays of shape (192,288) each containing the coefficients for "a" and "b" respectively. Im struggling to find an efficient way to do this.

Comment: you need to reshape your arrays so they are `Y.shape == (1_075_200, 1)` and `X.shape == (1_075_200, 2)`, then use `sklearn` as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479279/6692898)

Comment: Im not understanding your notation here with the subscores, or how that answers applies to multiple linear regression w 3D arrays... Can you elaborate in an actual answer?

Comment: even though you have 3D arrays, you are not trying to do multiple regressions with each of the dimensions in an array, you are actually trying to map the value in each position of both X arrays to the Y array... in other words, you don't really care about the shape of the arrays, you can flatten your arrays and use a multiple linear regression as in the linked answer

Comment: your new `X_data` would be an array of shape `(1075200, 2)`, one row for each datapoint and two columns for `X1 and X2`... underscore is just a thousands separator that is ignored by python when it is part of a number